# How exact do local citations need to be?

Tags: seo, local-seo, google-local-search

Since different directories will format entered information in different ways, how exact is really exact when it comes to cleaning up local citations?

Would these be considered "correct" or "incorrect"? That is, would they need to be cleaned up or not?

1. Cioccolata Bistro    Ågatan 24, 582 22 Linköping, Sweden  +46 13 13 18 80    cioccolata.nu
2. Cioccolata Bistro    Ågatan 24, 582 22 Linköping, Sweden 013-13 18 80    http://www.cioccolata.nu/
3. Cioccolata Bistro    Ågatan 24 Linköping, Sweden 582 23   +46 13 13 18 80    www.cioccolata.nu
4. Cioccolata Bistro    Ågatan 24 582 23 Linköping  13131880    -
5. Cioccolata Bistro    Ågatan 24, 582 23 Linköping 13131880    -
6. Cioccolata Bistro    Ågatan 24, Linköping, 582 23, Sweden    13131880    www.cioccolata.nu
7. Cioccolata Bistro    Ågatan 24 Linköping 13131880    www.cioccolata.nu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good citation is one that matches as **close as possible** to that of Bing Local or Google My Business, so options 1-7 are neither right or wrong, until you compare that to business listing.

It's important to note that your address should match that within the dashboard of Google My Business and Bing Local, not what they display in maps or snack box results as most often Google or Bing will remove or rename some things such as `Road` to `Rd` or remove the `County`.

Citations on 3rd parties should be as close as possible as its not always possible to have exact because just like Google and Bing, they will remove or rename certain parts of the address or number e.g `+447771234567` instead of `07771234567`, sometimes these 3rd parties won't ask for counties and other information. While its not disclosed how clever Google or Bing is when it comes to these variables we take the logic assumption that they are clever enough to understand that rd means road, st means street and so on.

*Short Answer:*

Ensure that your master citation is 100% correct (Bing and Google), then on 3rd party sites ensure that you fill in these sites as closely matched as Bing/Google, and expect that some sites will remove or rename some of the address line.

Website address is not closely linked into Google/Bing Local/Maps name, address, phone (NAP), so this is not that import. As long as your site links or redirects to the correct address the A HREF anchor (visit company, company name, www.example) is irrelevant.

*Tip:*

The most accurate place to find you correct address is by your national delivery/post office postcode checker, use that on Google/Bing.